# T-SQL Scalar-valued function Return Null value

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create a Scalar-valued user defined function to substitute my original codes. Basically, I intend to calculate the percentage of 2022 "nnooftickets" data out of the 2020 data for each period, there are 13 period in a year. Unfortunately, my user defined function codes do not work and I'm struggling spotting the issue.

The following are the original codes that works fine:

```
SELECT
setperiod,
SUM(nnooftickets) AS sumnnoofticketsp,
CASE
    WHEN setperiod like '2023%' THEN SUM(nnooftickets) *1.00 / LAG(SUM(nnooftickets),13*(2023-2020)) OVER(ORDER BY setperiod) ELSE null
    END AS nnoofticketspyoy
FROM rdg.Sales
GROUP BY setperiod
```

Then I created a scalar function try to replace the case statement, the codes for the scalar function is as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [rdg].[getyoy]
(
    @var BIGINT, @currentyear SMALLINT, @compareyear SMALLINT, @orderbyperiod VARCHAR, @multiplygap SMALLINT
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(18,4)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @YOY AS DECIMAL(18,4)
    SELECT @YOY = CASE WHEN @orderbyperiod like '2023%' THEN @Var*1.00 / LAG(@Var, @multiplygap*(@currentyear - @compareyear)) OVER (ORDER BY @orderbyperiod) ELSE null END
    RETURN @YOY
END
GO
```

Finally, I call the function using the codes below:

```
SELECT
setperiod,
SUM(nnooftickets) AS sumnnoofticketsp,
rdg.getyoy(SUM(nnooftickets), 2023, 2020, setperiod, 13) AS ngrosspyoy
FROM rdg.Sales
GROUP BY setperiod
```

However, after using the scalar function, there's no output figure (i.e. receive all NULL values) for column ngrosspyoy.

Could anyone help please?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're quoting here, so I've removed the quoteblock. If you *have* copied the SQL you put in quoteblocks from somewhere, please put it *back* into quoteblocks and following the [referencing guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Comment: `VARCHAR` without length is equivalent to `VARCHAR(1)`. So `@orderbyperiod` can never be `like '2023%'`

Comment: Your `SELECT` in your scalar function doesn't make any sense; what value are you expecting to be returned from the `LAG` when the `SELECT` only contains 1 row? There is no "prior" row. Your scalar function is return `NULL` because the `LAG` can *only* return `NULL` and thus the *entire* expression results in `NULL`.

Comment: Good point. You won't be able to encapsulate the `LAG` from the outer query into a function anyway as you are trying. It doesn't get any context about the outer query or is able to access any window from that. What does the underlying data look like that has set you off on this path?

Comment: Not related to why your code is bombing but scalar functions are bad and often perform poorly. Youre code was better off before.

Comment: Side note, SQL Server and Azure SQL Database are not the same thing; which are you actually using?

Comment: Thank you very much everyone, especially Larnu and Martin Smith. I really appreciate all your responses. I wrote those codes by myself, it's my first time asking a question on this site, so I was confused about the format. I'll remember not to put them in the quoteblock next time. I was thinking it might mainly due to the LAG but wasn't sure about that, thanks for pointing that out.